# How to get users email address from person or group field - using JSOM

Tags: list, javascript, jsom, people-picker, person-or-group

I have a field called Employee and it's a person and group field.
How can i get the users **email address** if i have the display name or the user id.
Any tip/help will be appreciated

See my snippet code below:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function StartersItems() {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Starters");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    var camlText = "<View><Query></Query></View>";

    camlQuery.set_viewXml(camlText);
    this.collListItem5 = list.getItems(camlQuery);

    context.load(collListItem5);
    context.executeQueryAsync(getNewStartersSuccess,getItemsFail);
}

function getNewStartersSuccess(sender,args){
    var listEnumerator = collListItem5.getEnumerator();

    i = 1;
    var newStarters = [];

    var newStartershtml= "";

    Startershtml+='<ul id="newStarterContainer">';


    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {

        var listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();

        //Employee is a person and Group field
        var employeeName = listItem.get_item("Employee").get_lookupValue();
        var employeeID = listItem.get_item("Employee").get_lookupId();

        //Can return these values no issue
        //console.log(employeeName);
        //console.log(employeeID);

        //Need help with a function to return email address here or use any of the Ids above
        FunctionToReturnEmailAddress(listItem.get_item("ID"));




    }
function getItemsFail(sender,args){
   console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

}

    </script>
```

Comment: Try using `var user = web.ensureUser(employeeName); var email = user.get_email();`

Answer (score 1):

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_siteUsers().getById(userid);
context.load(user);
context.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess),
    Function.createDelegate(null, onFail)
);

function ensureUserSuccess() {
    var email = user.get_email();
}

function onFail(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the email address or login name of user, you need to use `web.ensureUser()` method and then get the email or login name as below:

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getItemFromList, "sp.js");
function getItemFromList(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var item = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("MyTasks").getItemById(1);
    clientContext.load(item);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){ 
            // successfully retrieved value from list item
            var assigned = item.get_item("AssignedTo");
            if(assigned.length>0){
                var user = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(assigned[0].get_lookupValue());
                clientContext.load(user);
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
                    function(){ 
                        // successfully ensured user from user name
                        var email = user.get_email();
                        var login = user.get_loginName();
                        var displayName = user.get_title();
                        alert("User LoginName: " + login + "\nUser Email: " + email + "\nUser Display Name: " + displayName);
                    },function(sender,args){ // on error
                        alert(args.get_message());
                    }
                );
            }          
        },
        function(sender,args){ // on error
            alert(args.get_message());
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

**Reference**: [Retrieve displayName and email from person or group list field in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411602/retrieve-displayname-and-email-from-person-or-group-list-field-in-sharepoint)
.

**Solution for You**:

So for your case you can use your function like this:

```
function FunctionToReturnEmailAddress(employeeName) {
    var user = clientContext.get_web().ensureUser(employeeName);
    clientContext.load(user);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function(){ 
            // successfully ensured user from user name
            var email = user.get_email();
            var login = user.get_loginName();
            var displayName = user.get_title();
            alert("User LoginName: " + login + "\nUser Email: " + email + "\nUser Display Name: " + displayName);
        },function(sender,args){ // on error
            alert(args.get_message());
        }
    );
}
```

**Usage**:

```
FunctionToReturnEmailAddress(employeeName);
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh but how can i return the email value in executeQueryAsync?

Comment: Why do you want to return it? Either you can create a new function to write the remaining functionality and pass an email to that function or you can try using `return` to return the email and catch the result where the `FunctionToReturnEmailAddress` is called.

Comment: Thats exactly what im asking how to use return in the function you provided.It seems i cant use return with an async.Hope this makes sense...

Comment: I need to return the email as string with thia function

Comment: Can you create a new function and call this function after the `alert()` and pass an email as a parameter to the function?? Or you can use promise pattern with as JSOM as mentioned [here](http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/convert-sharepoint-jsoms-executequeryasync-to-promise-in-the-prototype) or [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139595/using-promises-with-executequeryasync-results-in-error).

Comment: Thanks but creating a function after the alert didn't work.It was just returning null when i use the function.Will be looking at other alternatives e.g using promises or callbacks. A good example would help

Comment: Have you tried it like: `function ShowEmail(emailAddresss) { console.log(emailAddresss); }` and call this function instead of alert like `var email = user.get_email();ShowEmail(email);`

Comment: Yes.. but where though? in the executeQueryAsync

Comment: Yes, try adding it in `executeQueryAsync`. Just after you set the variable to get the email of an user after it is ensured.

Comment: It doesn't work. have you tested this scenario on at your end?