# Retrieve Lookup metadata using Caml Query?

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, caml-query, managed-metadata

[image]
This "Initiator" is a person or Group column in SharePoint online. I need all metadata(email, key) of this column.

Comment: Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269455/how-to-get-users-email-address-from-person-or-group-field-using-jsom)

Comment: There is no verified answer in ur given link  Post @GaneshSanap

Answer (score 0):

you have to use
`web.ensureUser(fieldValue.get_lookupValue())` to retrieve user email,user id, and other properties.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411602/retrieve-displayname-and-email-from-person-or-group-list-field-in-sharepoint